# Angular 5 deployment to IIS server , navigation routes from dist folder not working

Tags: angular, iis, angular-cli, ng-build

From what I understand, if I do an ng build and deploy the code generated in the "dist" folder, then all the typescript and routing is all ready to work?!

I deployed code in `dist` folder and the home page comes up just fine

as soon as I click on a link, I get a 404   ( IIS server)

example of a route

```
/criminal/?UserID...


{ path: 'criminal', component: CriminalComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
```

Comment: In .angular-cli.json I set the outDir to wwwroot since that is what VS and IIS are usually looking for: --> "outDir": "wwwroot"

Comment: consider using [HashLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/guide/router#hashlocationstrategy)

Comment: Make sure you do a "ng build --prod" too before deployment. That will ensure that the core of your application is put together correctly and that there are no build errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow this tutorial:

https://blog.angularindepth.com/deploy-an-angular-application-to-iis-60a0897742e7

At a high level:

1. Install URL Rewrite
2. Handle subfolder and base URL as needed
3. Add web.config file to be deployed when you do an ng build